# How to "name" the results of an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I Can use the following code to allow a user to only choose one of the autocomplete options when filling out a form, works perfectly:

```
var validOptions = ["Bold", "Normal", "Default", "100", "200"]
previousValue = "";

$('#ac').autocomplete({
    autoFocus: true,
    source: validOptions
}).keyup(function() {
    var isValid = false;
    for (i in validOptions) {
        if (validOptions[i].toLowerCase().match(this.value.toLowerCase())) {
            isValid = true;
        }
    }
    if (!isValid) {
        this.value = previousValue
    } else {
        previousValue = this.value;
    }
});
```

However, I'm using ajax to create the array on the fly as below, so therefore I have no **name** for the array e.g. **validOptions** as above.

**QUESTION** How can I use the above 'way' with the below method

```
$('#ac').autocomplete({
    autoFocus: true,
    source: "/pages/includes/getAgent.php",
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#autoc1').val(ui.item.agent_name);
        $('#comm').val(ui.item.commission_percent);
        return false;
    }
    }).keyup(function() {
        var isValid = false;

        // here is the issue, the new data is not called validOptions
        for (i in validOptions) {
        if (validOptions[i].toLowerCase().match(this.value.toLowerCase())) {

            isValid = true;
        }
    }
        if (!isValid) {
            this.value = previousValue
        } else {
            previousValue = this.value;
        }
    }).data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li>" )
        .append( "<a>" + item.agent_name + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul )
    };
```

Comment: Where *is* the data stored then? Why can't you use `validOptions` to store the data?

Comment: @Juhana The data is stored in a Mysql table and brought in on the fly using autocomplete

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to use `keyup` event. Rather you will neeed to set `source` to function and make your own AJAX request. Within callback of that request test length of returned results for validity, or set server side return JSON with different properties to identify number of results and results themselves

See source code for [Remote Data with cache Demo](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache) as example for creating own AJAX in `source` function

Rather than change the value of the input which is unexpected behavior for user, you might want to set an error indicator and/or adjust your custom `_renderItem` method to display `No results` .This will allow user to see what what was entered in case it was a typo.

Another way to display `no results` is manipulate data within the AJAX callback if no values returned